# how to make 9patch button for this button

Tags: android, nine-patch

I want to make a button like this but I cant
Because when I convert it to 9patch the lines of button is scaling. But i want to repeat and full the button with lines

this is the original image
[image: this is the original image]

i want to be like this
[image: i want to be like this]

But it looks like this :(
[image: But it looks like this :(]

Comment: use a ShapeDrawable, setup a ShaderFactory that returns a BitmapShader

Answer (score 1):

Create a Bitmap Resource and repeat texture.

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/ab_texture_tile_apptheme"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

Comment: when I'm doing this the lines fills the whole image no just red part of the image

Comment: This is because of your round corners. I think you have to do some thing in coding. Create Bitmap by repeating texture and then round corners of image in java.

Comment: @Person you can find code for rounding corners here http://stackoverflow.com/a/3292810/1770916

Answer (score 1):

You only use 9patch when you scale some part of it. Based from your example image and you quote `lines of button is scaling` that is because of the 9patch.

Solution

Dont use 9patch just set it as a background Drawable/imageSource in your desire view

Comment: Thank you @Rod_Algonquin. Is there any other solution to make this. Can I do it with drawable xml's?

Comment: @Person just set it directly to a view so it will scale equally.. If those lines where not there you can make a 9patch

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
final float r = 32;
float[] outerRadii = {
        r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r
};
ShapeDrawable d = new ShapeDrawable(new RoundRectShape(outerRadii, null, null));
ShaderFactory factory = new ShaderFactory() {
    @Override
    public Shader resize(int width, int height) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        Shader shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, TileMode.REPEAT, TileMode.REPEAT);
        Matrix localM = new Matrix();
        localM.postRotate(45);
        shader.setLocalMatrix(localM);
        return shader;
    }
};
d.setShaderFactory(factory);

someView.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```